# WWarning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad instruction]

Tags: solidity, remix, address.transfer

When I invoke toll function, it encountered "Error encountered during contract execution [Bad instruction] " warning. Who knows why? thx

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
/// 使用0.4.24是为了moac链 - www.moac.io

/// @title 红包合约
/// @author yelvabaoji - xfshen@moacfoundation.cn
contract Redpack {
    address public owner;

    uint public minPackAmount = 1 * (10 ** 18); // 最低参与金额, 1 moac/mfc
    uint public maxPackAmount = 10000 * (10 ** 18); // 最高参与金额, 10000 moac/mfc
    uint public constant LIMIT_AMOUNT_OF_PACK = 100000 * (10 ** 18);

    uint public minPackCount = 1; // 最少1个红包可抢
    uint public maxPackCount = 10000; // 最多10000个红包可抢

    uint public totalPackAmounts = 0; // 该合约的余额
    uint public numberOfPlayers = 0; // 总的发红包数量
    address[] public players; // 发红包的人的列表

    struct Player {
        uint id; // 红包的id
        address owner; // 红包创建者的地址
        uint amount; // 红包里面塞钱塞了多少？
        uint balance; // 红包余额
        uint count; // 指定多少个红包数量
        uint amountPerPack; // 如果是均分，则每个红包的金额
        bool isRandom; // 指定是均分还是随机
        uint[] randomAmount; // 随机分配时，先产生count个随机数
        uint randomFactor; // 所有的随机数总和/count，用以计算最终的分配数
        address[] hunterList; // 抢红包的地址列表
        mapping(address => uint) hunterInfo; // 领取红包的人的列表：地址:数量
    }

    // 红包id到红包发红包人详细映射
    mapping(uint => Player) public playerInfo;

    // 这是为了人家发送币到合约地址的时候，收取
    function() public payable {}
    // event Received(address, uint);
    // receive() external payable { // receive关键字是solidity 6.0引进的
    //    emit Received(msg.sender, msg.value);
    // }
    // fallback() external payable;


    /// @notice 构造函数
    /// @param _minPackAmount 最小充钱数
    /// @param _maxPackAmount 最大充钱数
    constructor (uint _minPackAmount, uint _maxPackAmount) public {
        owner = msg.sender;

        if(_minPackAmount > 0) minPackAmount = _minPackAmount;
        if(_maxPackAmount > 0 && _maxPackAmount <= LIMIT_AMOUNT_OF_PACK)
            maxPackAmount = _maxPackAmount;
    }

    function kill() public {
        if(msg.sender == owner) selfdestruct(owner);
    }

    /// @notice 总红包数
    function getPlayerInfo() public view returns (
        uint nTotalPackAmounts,
        uint nNumberOfPlayers,
        address[] playerList
    ) {
        return (
        totalPackAmounts,
        numberOfPlayers,
        players
        );
    }

    //********************************************************************/
    // 创建红包
    //********************************************************************/

    event redpackCreated(uint id);
    event redpackWithdraw(uint amount);

    /// @notice 发红包充值
    /// @param count 可抢多少个红包
    /// @param isRandom 是固定分割还是随机分割
    // TODO 随机数生成方法需要改一下
    function toll(uint count, bool isRandom) public payable {
        require(msg.value >= minPackAmount && msg.value <= maxPackAmount, "amount out of range(1..10000");
        require(count >= minPackCount && count <= maxPackCount, "最少1个, 最多10000个");

        uint id = numberOfPlayers;
        playerInfo[id].amount = msg.value;
        playerInfo[id].balance = msg.value;
        playerInfo[id].count = count;
        playerInfo[id].isRandom = isRandom;
        playerInfo[id].id = id;
        if (isRandom) {
            uint total = 0;
            for (uint i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                playerInfo[id].randomAmount[i] = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(now, msg.sender, i))) % 100;
                total += playerInfo[id].randomAmount[i];
            }
            playerInfo[id].randomFactor = 100 / total; // 随机数按照 百分比计算足够了。
        } else {
            playerInfo[id].amountPerPack = msg.value / count; // 如果是均分的话，则每一份的金额是多少
        }

        totalPackAmounts += msg.value;
        numberOfPlayers++; // 创建的红包数量增加
        players.push(msg.sender); // player列表增加

        emit redpackCreated(id);
    }

    /// @notice 创建者提取余下的金额
    /// @param id 红包的id
    function withdrawBalance(uint id) public {
        require(msg.sender == playerInfo[id].owner, "not the owner.");
        require(playerInfo[id].balance > 0, "balance is 0.");
        require(playerInfo[id].balance <= totalPackAmounts, "not enough budget.");

        msg.sender.transfer(playerInfo[id].balance);
        totalPackAmounts -= playerInfo[id].balance;

        emit redpackWithdraw(playerInfo[id].balance);
    }

    /// @notice 某个红包统计信息
    /// @param id - 地址
    // 红包创建时间
    // 金额
    // 随机 / 平均
    // 个数
    // 余额
    // 已经抢了多少，还有多少
    function getPackInfo(uint id) public view returns (
        uint amount,
        uint balance,
        uint count,
        uint amountPerPack,
        bool isRandom
    ) {
        Player storage player = playerInfo[id];
        return (
        player.amount,
        player.balance,
        player.count,
        player.amountPerPack,
        player.isRandom
        );
    }

    //********************************************************************/
    // 抢红包
    //********************************************************************/

    event redpackGrabbed(uint amount);

    /// @notice 检查地址是否已经抢过该红包了。
    /// @param _id 哪一个红包
    /// @param _hunter 哪一个抢红包的人
    function checkHunterExists(uint _id, address _hunter) public view returns(bool) {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < playerInfo[_id].hunterList.length; i++){
            if(playerInfo[_id].hunterList[i] == _hunter) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /// @notice 抢红包。注意：抢完红包以后，抢的数据还保留着，以备查询
    /// @param id 抢的是哪一个红包
    function hunting(uint id) public payable {
        // 先检查该红包有没有余额
        require(playerInfo[id].balance > 0, "redpack is empty");
        require(playerInfo[id].count > playerInfo[id].hunterList.length, "exceed number of redpacks");
        require(!checkHunterExists(id, msg.sender), 'already grabbed');

        if(playerInfo[id].isRandom) {
            // 按照随机因子计算抢到的金额，这里可能有细微的误差
            uint index = playerInfo[id].hunterList.length;
            uint value = playerInfo[id].randomFactor * playerInfo[id].randomAmount[index] * playerInfo[id].amount;
            if (playerInfo[id].hunterList.length + 1 >= playerInfo[id].count) {
                // 考虑到计算的误差，最后一次抢红包，把余额全部发送出去
                hunted(id, playerInfo[id].balance);
                playerInfo[id].balance = 0;

            } else {
                hunted(id, value);
                playerInfo[id].balance -= value;
            }
        } else {
            // 考虑到计算的误差 (比如100块钱发给3个人红包平均分），最后一次抢红包，把余额全部发送出去
            if (playerInfo[id].balance > playerInfo[id].amountPerPack) {
                // 如果余额 > 1份，但是小于2份，则一次发送完毕
                if (playerInfo[id].balance < playerInfo[id].amountPerPack * 2) {
                    hunted(id, playerInfo[id].balance);
                    playerInfo[id].balance = 0; // 发送完成，余额为0
                } else {
                    // 如果余额 > 2份，则发送一份
                    hunted(id, playerInfo[id].amountPerPack);
                    playerInfo[id].balance -= playerInfo[id].amountPerPack;
                }
            } else {
                // 等于就是最后一个抢红包的人 （小于不可能）
                hunted(id, playerInfo[id].balance);
                playerInfo[id].balance = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    function hunted(uint _id, uint _amount) internal {
        require(_amount <= totalPackAmounts, "grab: not enough budget.");
        msg.sender.transfer(_amount);
        totalPackAmounts -= _amount;
        playerInfo[_id].hunterList.push(msg.sender);

        emit redpackGrabbed(_amount);
    }

    /// @notice 抢红包的记录，即在什么时间，抢了多少金额 - 这个可以通过查询我的特定交易记录来判断
    // function huntingRecord(uint id) public view returns () {
    // }

}
```

Comment: Have a look at Buidler + `console.log` to easily find out the line that reverts: https://dev.to/fvictorio/debugging-transactions-in-ethereum-part-2-truffle-and-buidler-36pp.

Comment: Are you testing in a private blockchain? What is your genesis file?